# Navigation bar items is not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My navigation bar is not collapsing the items once i resize my page to `width:750px;`. I have tried editing my css but still i am clueless. [This is my live page.](http://www.iconis.com.my)

This is my slidebar css:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { /* Slidebar width on extra small screens. */
.sb-slidebar {
    width: 70%;
}

.sb-width-thin {
    width: 55%;
}

.sb-width-wide {
    width: 85%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 481px) { /* Slidebar width on small screens. */
.sb-slidebar {
    width: 55%;
}

.sb-width-thin {
    width: 40%;
}

.sb-width-wide {
    width: 70%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { /* Slidebar width on small screens. */
.sb-slidebar {
    width: 40%;
}

.sb-width-thin {
    width: 25%;
}

.sb-width-wide {
    width: 55%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { /* Slidebar width on medium screens. */
.sb-slidebar {
    width: 30%;
}

.sb-width-thin {
    width: 15%;
}

.sb-width-wide {
    width: 45%;
}

#logo {
    text-align: left;
}
ul.navbar-nav {
    display: none;
}

}

@media (min-width: 1200px) { /* Slidebar width on large screens. */
.sb-slidebar {
    width: 20%;
}

.sb-width-thin {
    width: 5%;
}

.sb-width-wide {
    width: 35%;
}
#logo {
    text-align: left;
}
ul.navbar-nav {
    display: none;
}
}
```

This is my style.css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
#logo {
    text-align: left;
}
ul.navbar-nav {
    display: block;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1199px) {
ul.navbar-nav {
    display: block;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top sb-slide" role="navigation">


    <div class="container">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div id="logo" class="navbar-left">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/rsz_iconis-logo.jpg" alt="Iconis Logo" width="auto" height="40"></a>
        </div><!-- /#logo -->

        <!-- Menu -->
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right' id="navigate">
                <li data-slide='1'><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li data-slide='2'><a href="#">Digital Ecosystem</a></li>
                <li data-slide='3'><a href="#">Fellow & Members</a></li>
                <li data-slide='4'><a href="#">SIGs</a></li>
                <li data-slide='5'><a href="#">Local Chapters</a></li>
                <li data-slide="7"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li data-slide="8"><a href="#">Our Service</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
```

I just want it to hide my menu items once i resize my screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nav element on the page is never hidden when the page is resized to 750px or lower.

With the following media query the nav element in your bootstrap navigation element will set to display: none if the screen is 750px or lower.

```
@media screen and (max-width : 750px) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your post was flagged as low quality post. Please try to improve your answer by adding an explanation why you changed the code this way.